# redirect_uri_mismatch through InstalledAppFlow but working fine when accesing the url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to integrate google calendar with Django but getting **redirect_uri_mismatch**
error everytime I try to login using google. If I put the raw url i.e  [https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={client_id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&response_type=token&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D&scope=%7Bscope%7D) and replace the redirect_uri then it works but not through InstalledAppFlow. Please help as there is nothing mentioned for this on the GCP documentation too.

Comment: The Redirect URI does not match what your code is specifying. Make sure that items like **https** are a match.

Comment: It is working fine now but for a certain client_secret file only. If i try to create another one with the same redirect url it starts to throw the same error. There is definitely a flaw with GCP.